# JavaScript CSS change is only for a second?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some JavaScript that is supposed to change the display property from none to block.  What happens is it flashes on the screen then goes away in half a second.

```
<input type="image" src="images/joinButton.jpg" name="join" value="Join" onclick="check(this.form)" />

function check(form){
        var errorFields = document.getElementById('errorFields');
        errorFields.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: `input` tag closed by a `button` tag? plus, the question is too vague. could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: it might be interfere's with other events, maybe you could check your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Robert - Can you edit and clean up your HTML as pointed out by @naveen?  You're mixing HTML elements that don't belong together, like input and button.  Is that really how your HTML looks on your page or is that just a typo in the question? Thanks!

Comment: wow i can't believe i did that.  that was actually how it looked on the page.  It's fixed now but problem is the same

Comment: I see `getElementById('errorFields')` <- by the name it suggests and I assume there are more than one `errorFields`, then why would they all have the same ID? they should have the same class instead.

Comment: @DMin — looks like a container with multiple error fields inside it. `<foo id="bars"><bar/><bar/><bar/></foo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is probably happening:

1. Image clicked
2. Styles changed
3. Form submitted
4. Page reloaded with original styles

You need to return false from the event handler to cancel the normal operation of the image map if you don't want the form to submit.

```
onclick="return check(this.form)"


function check(form){
    var errorFields = document.getElementById('errorFields');
    errorFields.style.display = 'block';
    return false;
}
```

You would probably be better off using [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and replacing the image map's click event with the form's submit event though.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the style display via javascript should stick unless something else is happening after it that changes it back.  For example, try this code in a new html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
    var errorFields = document.getElementById('errorFields');
    errorFields.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="errorFields" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 300px; width: 300px; display: none;"></div>
<input type="button" name="join" value="Join" onclick="check()" />
</body>
</html>
```

It'll make a red box appear after you click the button.  What's likely happening is there's another event tied to your button click that's happening after your check() function, so it displays, and then hides immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the flashing occurs is because you most likely have a conflict between your CSS and your JavaScript (or another JavaScript function being called that is hiding the content).

Also, the style.display property may not work properly in all browsers. I suggest the following:

```
errorFields.style.display = "block";
errorFields.setAttribute("style","display:block");
```

I also suggest using a tool like Firebug to inspect the elements and see what other CSS is being applied to your element so you can detect the conflict.

Comment: that is the only javascript i have on the page currently but how could css conflict with the javascript?

Comment: @Robert - If there is a CSS rule in your HEAD that applies to that element, and that CSS is applied *after* your JavaScript runs, this could cause the conflict. Check your CSS and make sure you don't have a rule that has a display:none attached to your element. There are other properties that could cause your element to hide as well that have a similar root cause. Also, check Firebug and inspect the elemnent to see if there is a display:none on your elements or anything that may indicate a conflict :)  Good luck!